# Distinct rows on Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to display data with a pivot table with a distinct of rows

**Data**

```
Id | Date       | Count | Date 2     | ...
1  | 21/02/2020 | 1     |            | ...
1  | 21/02/2020 | 1     | 21/02/2020 | ...
2  | 15/05/2021 | 0     | 15/05/2021 | ...
3  | 17/09/2020 | 2     | 17/09/2020 | ...
3  | 17/09/2020 | 2     | 19/10/2021 | ...
3  | 17/09/2020 | 2     | 25/11/2021 | ...
```

**Expected result in the Pivot Table**

```
Id | Date       | Count
1  | 21/02/2020 | 1
2  | 15/05/2021 | 0
3  | 17/09/2020 | 2
```

Can you please explain me quickly how to setup the Pivot Table to get this result ?

Indeed, I'm getting 2 for `id 1` and 6 for `id 3` ... `SUM` is performed (instead of 1 and 2).

Moreover, I'm not able to put the value of the `Date` as a column ...

Maybe that Pivot Table is not the correct way to do it.

I hope it is clear ...

Many thanks in advance

Comment: To achieve your Expected result, you can use a pivot table where you put those 3 fields in your "rows" value. Then change your design to Tabular mode, do not show Grand or Sub totals. You could also simply copy those 3 columns, and paste elsewhere, then will all 3 columns highlighted do to Data and remove duplicates. But if your question is truly around how to avoid duplicates, then click the "add this data to data model" when you create your pivot table. It will give you an additional Value Field setting where you can summarize "distinct count". But I don't see the need based on your example.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Tabular mode seems to fit with my need ! Indeed, `distinct count` is not the need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding the answer per the comment..

To achieve your Expected result, you can use a pivot table where you put those 3 fields in your "rows" value. Then change your design to Tabular mode, do not show Grand or Sub totals.

You could also simply copy those 3 columns, and paste elsewhere, then with all 3 columns highlighted do to Data and remove duplicates.